# How to rewrite ajax get request to post request (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a GET request:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/items?ids=' + value.join(','),
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

How can I create a POST request from this?

Comment: Just change the method name POST

Comment: But your server must be implemented in such a way that it handles both the requests...

Comment: It's not enough. I dont need to pass arguments in url.

Comment: This is a prime example of why you should always read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax. There's nothing anyone can tell you here which you shouldn't have already researched yourself

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'url_here',
   method: 'post',
   data: {
       fName1: value1,
       fName2: value2,
       ...
   },
   dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: I dont need to pass arguments in url.

Answer (score 0):

The way of post requests works are different from the get request, in http post request you need to pass the values in the body of your request as bellow :

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/items",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "id": $("#id").val(),
                    "value1": $("#value1").val(),
                    "value2": $("#value2").val()
                }
            });
```

you can use fiddler to debug and watch what going on the wire.